# How to Frame Camera Preview in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have some frames in my SD card.

There is list of frames in my activity.

Now when user click on frame, Camera preview will be displayed through that frame.

Please see image.

[image]

How can I archive this functionality ?

I searched about this but didn't get proper example.

Comment: you can use framelayout over preview and set whatever image

Answer (score 4):

You have to create your own Preview by extending the SurfaceView class.

Take FrameLayout with SurfaceView as child.and customise as per your needs

You can use `SurfaceView` and create a `CustomView` that will open the camera and you can adjust its size in the `xml` accordingly.

Create a class that `extends SurfaceView` and open camera inside that

> CustomPreview.java

```
public class CustomPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    public static Bitmap mBitmap;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    static Camera mCamera;

    public CustomPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
    /***
     * 
     *  Take a picture and and convert it from bytes[] to Bitmap.
     *  
     */
    public static void takeAPicture(){  

        Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
            }
        };
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
    }
}
```

> Now you can add this custom view in your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <FrameLayout 
  android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.mjl.CustomPreview 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </com.mjl.CustomPreview>

  </FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_below="@id/mySurfaceView" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:gravity="center">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImageView" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
  </LinearLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now Enjoy the output.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I will integrate this solution and will be back.